# How do I find a string keyword and paste something to the row below it when the string is matched?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am very new to VBA. I am trying to write a macro that will search for the word "date" in all the header names (all variables names in Row 1) and will copy a cell (from another sheet) into the row under the headers where the matches are found (Row 2).

The pasting part does not work currently and I am having it search the whole workbook as I did not know how to set it to search only the header row.

```
Sub FindAndPaste()

Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Loc As Range

For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With Sheet.UsedRange
    Set Loc = .Cells.Find(What:="date")
    If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
        Do Until Loc Is Nothing
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L3").Copy
            Loc.Value.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            Set Loc = .FindNext(Loc)
        Loop
    End If
End With
Set Loc = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

I also tried changing the part inside the Do Until loop by changing it to the code below but that did not seem to work either.

```
Do Until Loc Is Nothing
    copiedval = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L3").Copy
    Loc.Value.Offset(1, 0).Value = copiedval
    Set Loc = .FindNext(Loc)
Loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be more straightforward without using Find()

It's not clear whether you're looking for cells which *contain* date, or just cells with the value "date".

Or whether you want to exclude Sheet1 from the search

```
Sub FindAndPaste()

    Dim Sheet, wb As workbook
    Dim c As Range, arrSheets

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    arrSheets = Array(wb.sheets("Sheet2"), wb.sheets("Sheet3"))

    For Each Sheet In arrSheets
        For Each c in Sheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Cells
            If c.value like "*date*" Then
                wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L3").Copy c.Offset(1,0)
                c.Offset(1,0).NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd" '<<<<<<<<<EDIT 
            End If
        Next c
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Yesss! this is it! Thank you @Tim Williams

Comment: I see what you mean about excluding Sheet 1 from the search. I actually just needed it to go through 2 different sheets so I just copied this macro twice and set the sheet to be sheet 2 in one macro and sheet 3 in another `Set Sheet = Sheets("Sheet 2")` i needed it to contain the word "date" just like you coded it.

Comment: @TimWilliams, just to say that `Sheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Cells` isn't bound to return the _real_ row 1 of Sheet1 ...

Comment: @user3598756 - I know that, but since the OP expects their headers in Row 1 then in this case it should.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I guessed that. I wanted to point it out just for other people reading this post and with possible different (more general) needs as to this specific issue

Comment: @user3598756 - agreed it's something which is often assumed and doesn't always hold true...

Comment: @TimWilliams  is there a way to not only copy the string in "L3"  which is actually a text sating "YYYY-MM-DD" to let the user know this is what I want you to enter here but also enfroce a yyyy/mm/dd format? I tried adding this inside the IF statement but they dont seem to work `.NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"` I also tried `'ActiveSheet.Name = Format$(Date, "yyyy/mm/dd")`

Comment: See my edit - not following what you want to do with the sheet name but you cannot use `/` there...

Comment: @TimWilliams That did it! thank you once again, you are my hero!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub FindAndPaste()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Loc As Range, founds As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set founds = sht.Cells(2,1)
    With Intersect(sht.Rows(1), sht.UsedRange)
        Set Loc = .Find(What:="date", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = Loc.Address
            Do
                Set founds = Union(founds, Loc)
                Set Loc = .FindNext(Loc)
            Loop While Not Loc.Address <>firstAddress
            Intersect(.Cells,founds).Offset(1).Value =Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L3").Value
        End If
    End With
Next sht

End Sub
```

While if you need to find a header containg "date" than just substitute `LookAt:=xlWhole` with `LookAt:=xlPart`